# Heroku Angular 4 App, CSP Errors upon refresh

Tags: angular, heroku, content-security-policy

I am trying to get my application running on heroku. I have followed many tutorials that allow me to run it with express server. Running locally I have no problems and application runs great on Heroku. However, when I try to access a child route directly or refresh my application I see:

```
Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGVUABEAAAAAxuQAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHREVGAAABgAAAAC4AAAA0ArgC7UdQT1MAAAGwAAAQ6AAALgxKsqRTR1NVQgAAEpgAAAH3AAAELqI5y+RPUy8yAAAUkAAAAE8AAABgaGyBu2NtYXAAABTgAAABlAAAAkQkRATXY3Z0IAAAFnQAAABeAAAAugDsQf1mcGdtAAAW1AAABZcAAAvNb3/BHGdhc3AAABxsAAAACAAAAAgAAAAQZ2x5ZgAAHHQAAEApAAB3CtbiupxoZWFkAABcoAAAADYAAAA2BkubWWhoZWEAAFzYAAAAIAAAACQHFARfaG10eAAAXPgAAAI6AAAEEk4TN4Nsb2NhAABfNAAAAhIAAAISiLhpam1heHAAAGFIAAAAIAAAACACigzgbmFtZQAAYWgAAACUAAABHhQGLdJwb3N0AABh/AAAAq4AAASRk5y6n3ByZ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Its tough to know if this was a deployment issue or some sort of csp configuration I turned on. I tried writing:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'unsafe-inline' data: ;">
```

in my Iindex.html but kept recieving the same errors. What appears to be the problem?

I am using Material Icons cdns:

## Package json

```
{
  "name": "temp-sensor",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "4.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.3",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

## server.js

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('/index.html')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to fix the refresh error for Angular sites.

In the **index.html** of your site

```
<base href="./index.html">
```

Next in **app.module.ts**

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

Now add them to the **Providers** within the **app.module.ts**

providers: [OtherName, {provide:LocationStrategy, useClass:HashLocationStrategy}],

**Note** that this will add a # tag to your routes!

Now deploy the site and try to refresh.

Comment: This solved it for me.  Why is it that the `HashLocationStrategy` solves the issue?  It is not required to chance the base href in the `index.html` btw.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem deploying on heroku and For me it helped to use npm package `serve` instead of using `server.js` script
So I added this on package.json scripts
        `"start": "serve -s dist",`